# Return an sql variable's value from within an Oracle Sql Query back to .NET code

Tags: c#, oracle, variables, select, ado.net

For the past few hours I am trying to do the simplest of the simple things (at least for SQL SERVER) in an Oracle Data Base, through a .NET application using ADO.NET. It seems impossible.

For SQL SERVER I would do this simple task, supposing I have an SqlCommand object

```
comm.CommandText = @"
   DECLARE @next_id INT
   SET @next_id = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id_col),0) FROM TABLE_1) + 1
   INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (id_col, col1, ...) VALUES (@next_id, val1, ...)
   SELECT @next_id";
int id = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());
```

That would insert a new record to table TABLE_1 and I would take back the new id in the "id" variable in c# code.

Four simple steps

- Declare a variable
- Set it to the next available id
- Insert the record with the new variable
- Return the variable's value

Ok I managed to declare the variable in Oracle query. Also I (think) I managed to give it a value (With SELECT INTO)

How can I get back this variable's value back in c#? How can i SELECT a variable's value to the output stream in Oracle SQL?

*I know that there are better ways to achieve getting back an identity column, but that's not the question here. It could be a totally different example. The question is simple.*: I have declared a variable inside an oracle sql script that will be executed from within .net app. **How can i get the variable's value back to c#, from an oracle query?** What is the above code's equivalent with Oracle ADO.NET query?

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) (Oracle's Oracle Data Access Components):

An example of this is below.  Note that in ODP.NET, you can establish a parameters direction (input, inputoutput, output, returnvalue) to correspond with the parameters of the procedure or statement you're running.  In this example, I'm grabbing a returnvalue, which is an ID that is generated by the db via a sequence and trigger (its created automagically as far as the .NET app is concerned):

```
int event_id = 0;
using (OracleConnection oraConn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
{
    string cmdText = @"insert into EVENT
        (EVENT_NAME, EVENT_DESC)
        values
        (:EVENT_NAME, :EVENT_DESC)
        RETURNING EVENT_ID INTO :EVENT_ID
        ";

    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdText, oraConn))
    {
        oraConn.Open();
        OracleTransaction trans = oraConn.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            OracleParameter prm = new OracleParameter();
            cmd.BindByName = true;
            prm = new OracleParameter("EVENT_NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2); 
            prm.Value = "SOME NAME"; cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);

            prm = new OracleParameter("EVENT_DESC", OracleDbType.Varchar2); 
            prm.Value = "SOME DESC"; cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);

            prm = new OracleParameter( "EVENT_ID"
                                     , OracleDbType.Int32
                                     , ParameterDirection.ReturnValue); 
            cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trans.Commit();
            // return value
            event_id = ConvertFromDB<int>(cmd.Parameters["EVENT_ID"].Value);
        }
        catch
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            trans.Dispose();
        }
        oraConn.Close();
    }
}
```

The ConvertFromDB is just a generic to cast the return value to its .NET equivalent (an int in this case).

Hope that helps.

EDIT:

You can easily bind an array of values (and retrieve an array of return values) in ODP.NET:

```
using (OracleConnection oraConn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
{
    string cmdText = @"insert into TEST_EVENT
        (EVENT_NAME, EVENT_DESC)
        values
        (:EVENT_NAME, :EVENT_DESC)
        RETURNING EVENT_ID INTO :EVENT_ID
        ";

    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdText, oraConn))
    {
        oraConn.Open();
        OracleTransaction trans = oraConn.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            string[] event_names = new string[2];
            string[] event_descs = new string[2];
            int[] event_ids = new int[2];

            event_names[0] = "Event1";
            event_descs[0] = "Desc1";

            event_names[1] = "Event2";
            event_descs[1] = "Desc2";

            OracleParameter prm = new OracleParameter();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.ArrayBindCount = 2;
            cmd.BindByName = true;

            prm = new OracleParameter("EVENT_NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2); 
            prm.Value = event_names; cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);

            prm = new OracleParameter("EVENT_DESC", OracleDbType.Varchar2); 
            prm.Value = event_descs; cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);

            prm = new OracleParameter( "EVENT_ID"
                                     , OracleDbType.Int32
                                     , ParameterDirection.ReturnValue); 
            cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            trans.Commit();
            // get return values

            event_ids = (int[])(cmd.Parameters["EVENT_ID"].Value);
        }
        catch
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            trans.Dispose();
        }
        oraConn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, actually this does not answer the question, even though it is helpful. The question is how to get in the c# code the value of a variable (not parameter) that is declared and initialized within the sql script.

But I want to ask you,
1) Does the solution you provide changes anything to the DB's schema?
2) Does an insert statement always outputs the id in the Return Parameter?
3) What about having two INSERTs in the script? Which one's id is returned?

Comment: Also, what about TABLES that do not have an autoincrement strategy (sequence or whatever it is)? How would you return the id in such cases? (provided that everything is executed in the context of a transaction)

Comment: @Saysmaster see my edits above for binding arrays of values (and getting an array of return values).  As for the id values, you would either need to provide the ID value in the insert statement, or you would have Oracle generate it (via the trigger/seq approach) and return it for you.