# How to use Last_Insert_Id() in Insert Statement of Oracle in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, sqlplus

i have tried many solution mentioned but none has returned Value,
I'm using C# asp.net, and SQL*Plus(9.1.0) database(Oracle);

I need to insert a record into a table for which Seq and Trigger to Increment the Id are created, after Inserting i need to get the Inserted record's Id back for reference.
How to write C# Command to get the last Id as output, have tried many, but no luck, even in database records are insering but nothing is returning back,

```
String Qry = "Insert into test1(Id,Name) values(1,'Hello') RETURNING Id INTO :LASTID";

    OracleParameter lastId = new OracleParameter(":LASTID", OracleType.Int32);       
    lastId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(Qry, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(lastId);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblId.Text= lastId.Value.ToString();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Have tried in Database as well, but SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); didn't work Returns Nothing. Please provide with any Working C# code.
If nothing works i will go on with Max(Id) statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RETURNING INTO with odp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215454/return-an-sql-variables-value-from-within-an-oracle-sql-query-back-to-net-code/12216375#12216375)